# RIP versus OSPF

Tags: cisco, ospf, rip, eigrp

If in my network there is a `RIP`, `EIGRP`, `OSPF` then a request is sent and It may pass to any of the 3 protocols, which among the three has the highest priority or the protocol that is being executed?

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. I see that you've been able to get a complete answer + reference from someone already, but be aware that in the future, homework questions will likely be closed before anyone has a chance to answer. If you have a problem with a homework question, 1) be honest about it, 2) tell us what you think the answer is, 3) tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Administrative distance is the feature that routers use in order to select the best path when there are two or more different routes to the same destination from two different routing protocols. Administrative distance defines the reliability of a routing protocol.

List with routing protocols and administrative distances:

- `EIGRP 90`
- `OSPF 110`
- `RIP 120`

In your case `EIGRP` has the smallest administrative distance and this protocol will be determine the route.

Comment: thank you. It would be better If you can give me the reference. please

Comment: This is good article http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/15986-admin-distance.html